# Apache virtualhosts.conf wildcard

Tags: apache, wildcard-subdomain

I have a VM windows server 2022 running XAMPP. The server is named **server2022**.
I will browse localy and remote to this server.

**What I want is:**

http(s)://localhost -> show default content of xampp/htdocs/

http(s)://server2022 -> show default content of xampp/htdocs/

http(s)://**sitename**.localhost -> show default content of xampp/htdocs/websites/**sitename**/httpdocs

http(s)://**sitename**.server2022 -> show default content of xampp/htdocs/websites/**sitename**/httpdocs

To achieve this I edited **httpd-vhost.conf**

```
UseCanonicalName off

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
        DocumentRoot "W:/xampp/htdocs/"
        ServerName server2022
    ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
        ServerAlias *.localhost
    ServerAlias *.server2022
        VirtualDocumentRoot "W:/xampp/htdocs/websites/%-2/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Rule 1 works for both (on the browser form the server localy)

Rule 2 only works for locahost.

Any Ideas for fixing this are welcome?